# Flex DataGrid/List Drag and Drop - How to avoid copying

Tags: apache-flex

I'm using drag and drop on a DataGrid to reorder items. However, when the user holds down Ctrl he can initiate a drag Copy operation. How can I disable copying altogether? (not just cancel the drop, but also prevent Ctrl + drag from showing the (+) icon)

Comment: Which SDK are you using? Flex 3 or 4?

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me (for a spark List):

```
<s:List dragEnabled="true" dropEnabled="true" dragMoveEnabled="true"
dragEnter="{event.ctrlKey = false}" dragOver="{event.ctrlKey = false}">
...
</s:List>
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be the following:

1. Listen for keydown events on the datagrid. If the user is holding down CTRL, set a dirty flag
2. Listen for dragStart event on the datagrid. Check to see if the dirty flag is set to true, if it is, then event.preventDefault() should kill any dragging.

Don't forget to reset the dirty flag as required.

Comment: Trying it. preventDefault during dragStart doesn't seem to cancel the drag operation..

Answer (score 0):

```
To avoid the copying use dragDropHandler() in which you can check weather the cntrl key is pressed while dragging, if yes you can restrict the dragdrop.  

protected function myTree_dragDropHandler(event:DragEvent):void { 
           if(event.ctrlKey== true) {
                 event.preventDefault();
                 cvTree.hideDropFeedback(event);
                 return;
           }
}
```